# Extending an automorphism from a sub-algebra to the algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, automorphisms

Let $A \subseteq B$ be two (associative with $1$) $k$-algebras, where $k$ is a field of characteristic zero, and let $f$ be a $k$-automorphism of $A$.

I am interested to know 'when' one can extend $f$ to a $k$-automorphism of $B$.

Three nice answers:
(1) [This question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192281/inner-and-extendible-automorphisms-of-c-algebras) deals with $C^*$-algebras. 
(2) [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002290200276) deals with extending involutions on Frobenius algebras.
(3) [A counter-example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406080/extending-automorphisms-in-complete-boolean-algebras) for Boolean algebras.

Since my question is too general, I do not mind to concentrate on commutative algebras only (which are not fields), and $f$ of finite order (for example, $f$ is an involution, namely, of order $2$).

Thank you very much for any comment.

Comment: I do not know the answer but i think your question is intimately connected to http://mathoverflow.net/q/111881/85967.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Indeed, an answer to the question you cited should help to answer my question also.

Comment: When $f$ is, say an involution, there are 2 distinct questions (1) whether $f$ extends (2) whether $f$ extends to an involution.

Comment: Curves of genus $\ge 2$ have finite automorphism group. Hence there are many 1-dimensional domains (f.g. over field $k$) $A$ with an embedding of $k[t]$ (or $k[t,t^{-1}]$), and very few of the automorphism of these subfield will extend.

Comment: Easier and more explicit: if $A\subset B=A[1/u]$, then an automorphism of $A$ extending to $B$ implies geometrically that it corresponds to an automorphism of variety stabilizing the zero locus of $f$. This yields to an obvious example: the automorphism $t\mapsto 1-t$ (of order 2) of $R[t]$ ($R$ any nonzero commutative ground ring, where we work in $R$-algebras) does not extend to $R[t,t^{-1}]$ (direct argument: because in the large ring $t$ is invertible but not $1-t$).

Comment: @YCor, thanks for you comments! Concerning your first comment, I would elaborate (1) whether $f$ extends to an endomorphism or to an automorphism (is this what you meant?). Your second and third comments are interesting (you can write them as an answer if you like, though I had in mind different algebras than your counter-example).

Comment: Whether it extends to an endomorphism is another question, but in my example it doesn't, by the same argument. On the other hand, for localization of domains, the possible extension is unique and hence if $f^n$ and the extension $g$ exists, then $g^n=1$.

Comment: Here's one localization where $f$ extends to an endomorphism but not an automorphism: assume that $R$ is a domain of characteristic zero, and consider the inclusion $A=R[t]\subset B=S^{-1}R[t]$, where $S=\{t+n:n\ge 0\}$. Then $f:t\mapsto t+1$ extends from $A$ to $B$, but the unique extension is not surjective, since $t^{-1}$ is not in the image.

Comment: Very nice! What about polynomial rings? Do you think you can prove or give a counter-example in that case?

Comment: Simpler (but not domains): $k\times k\subset k\times k[t]$: the flip (of order 2) extends to an endomorphism, but not to an automorphism.

Comment: You need to specify what is supposed to be polynomial ring: the small or the large ring?

Comment: I am not sure, perhaps each of the three options is interesting for me: (1) A is a polynomial ring. (2) B is a polynomial ring. (3) Both $A$ and $B$ are polynomial rings (with the same Krull dimension).

Comment: I guess one can find a counter-example for (1) and for (2)? But (3) seems to me more difficult  (it seems true to me, but I do not have a proof yet).

Comment: When $A$ is a polynomial ring I already gave you examples. With $A$ and $B$ both polynomial rings, take $B=k[t,u]$ and $A=k[t,u^2]\subset B$. Then the flip $t\leftrightarrow u^2$ of $A$ does not extends to an automorphism of $B$, since $t$ is not a square in $B$ but $u^2$ is. Variant with one variable: $B=k[t]$, $A=k[t^2]\subset B$. Then writing $u=t^2$, the automorphism of $A$ mapping $u$ to $u+1$ does not extend, since $u+1$ is not a square in $B$ (assuming $k$ not of char 2) while $u$ is.

Comment: Nice counter-example!

Comment: In your counter-example for (3), the Jacobian of $\{t,u^2\}$ is $2u$ which is not invertible in $k[t,u^2]$. What if $A$ is generated by two elements of $B$ that have an invertible Jacobian (namely, in $k^*$) ?. This case I had in mind when I have said that it seems true to me, but I do not have a proof yet.

Comment: Such $A \subseteq B$ is a separable ring extension. Perhaps this should help somehow?

Comment: Even for finite field extensions of $k = \mathbb Q$ there are counterexamples! For example, the conjugation on $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ cannot be extended to an automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2})$, since $\sqrt{2}$ is a square in the latter but $-\sqrt{2}$ isn't (e.g. use a real embedding $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{2}) \to \mathbb R$ to see this).

Comment: If two elements of $k[x,y]$ have invertible Jacobian, unless I miss something, the Jacobian conjecture tells you that the pair generates the polynomial ring. So this is unlikely to give any example.

Comment: Exactly, and this is why I have said that this case seems true to me (because I "believe" in a positive answer to the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture). However, I do not know yet how to prove that an involution on $T:=k[p,q]$ extends to an involution on $k[x,y]$, where $k[p,q] \subseteq k[x,y]$ and $\{p,q\}$ have an invertible Jacobian. I only think I know how to prove that this implies the two-dimensional Jacobian Conjecture (and it is enough to consider involutions on $T$ with Jacobian $-1$).

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, thanks for your counter-example.

Comment: Indeed, @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, I just gave a relatively elementary talk taking off from the same example you give, arguing that for a finite separable extension of fields, you can *hardly ever* extend an automorphism of the smaller field to the larger.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, but what if we further assume that the field $k$ is also algebraically closed (in addition of being of characteristic zero)? Can you still find a counter-example? (I am curious to know if in Lubin's talk the fields are algebraically closed). Thanks.

Comment: Clearly there are no examples where both $A$ and $B$ are *finite* field extensions of $k$ (since $k$ is algebraically closed). However, in my answer I give many examples where $A$ and $B$ are transcendence degree $1$ field extensions of an algebraically closed field $k$.

Comment: @Lubin, thank you, sounds interesting. Please do you have any notes/references of your recent talk?

Comment: Comparatively preliminary. I’d rather not put a URL out here. If you’re interested, e-mail me. I have to say that in the comment above, I overstated my thesis. The notes that I have concentrate on a situation where the automorphism group of the downstairs field is a topological group, and the extendable elements of it form a subgroup of finite index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer to your question is: almost never. Many counterexamples have already been constructed in the comments. Let me make another easy counterexample:

**Example.** Let $k$ be algebraically closed, and let $A = k[t]$, $B = k[\sqrt{t}] = k[x]$. Consider the automorphism $t \mapsto t+1$ of $A$. It cannot be extended to $B$, since $t+1$ is not a square in $B$ (equivalently, $x^2 + 1$ is not a square in $k[x]$).

**Example.** Similarly, the automorphism $t \mapsto t+1$ of $k(t)$ cannot be extended to $k(\sqrt{t})$. Thus, even for a finite extension of fields containing an algebraically closed field $k$, it is false in general.

**Remark.** This example is actually rather instructive, because $k[t]$ has *many* automorphisms: any $a,b \in k$ with $a \neq 0$ give rise to the automorphism $t \mapsto at + b$. When $b \neq 0$, this cannot be extended to $k[\sqrt{t}]$.

Similarly, the automorphisms of $k(t)$ over $k$ are given by $PGL_2(k)$. Indeed, automorphisms of $k(t)$ are the same thing as automorphisms of $\mathbb P^1$, since the category of transcendence degree $1$ field extensions of $k$ is equivalent to the category of smooth projective curves over $k$ with surjective maps.

Clearly a necessary criterion for an automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$ to extend to the double cover $\mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$ is that it preserves the branch locus $\{[0:1],[1:0]\}$. The only matrices that do this are $$\pmatrix{a & b\\c & d} \in PGL_2(k)$$ with either $b = c = 0$ or $a = d = 0$. This corresponds to the automorphisms $t \mapsto \lambda t$ or $t \mapsto \lambda t^{-1}$. Another way to see this is by letting the automorphism act on the complement $\mathbb A^1\setminus\{0\}$ of $\{[0:1],[1:0]\}$. This is given by $k[t,t^{-1}]$, and an endomorphism must map $t$ to an invertible element, i.e. to some $\lambda t^k$. It's an automorphism iff $k = \pm 1$.

Finally, these do indeed extend to automorphisms of the overlying $\mathbb P^1$, by $x \mapsto \sqrt{\lambda}\cdot x^{\pm 1}$. But this is really just a coincidence:

**Remark.** For a morphism of curves $C \to D$ and an automorphism $\phi$ of $D$, it is not in general sufficient for $\phi$ to fix the branch locus in order for it to lift to an automorphism of $C$. For example, let $C$ be a general curve of genus $\geq 3$. Then $C$ has no nontrivial automorphisms; see e.g. the various answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/54994/82179). In particular, we can choose such $C$ to be defined over $\bar{\mathbb Q}$.

But if $C$ is defined over $\bar {\mathbb Q}$, then Belyi's theorem it admits a map to $\mathbb P^1$ ramified at three points only. (It should in principle be possible to write down an *explicit* example of a curve admitting a map to $\mathbb P^1$ ramified at three points and with no nontrivial automorphisms, but I don't have one at hand.)

Then any permutation of the branch locus can be realised by some automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$ (since $PGL_2(k)$ acts transitively on triples of points in $\mathbb P^1$), but this map cannot be extended to $C$ since $C$ has no automorphisms.

This gives more examples of transcendence degree $1$ field extensions $A \subseteq B$ of $k$ where a $k$-automorphism of $A$ does not extend to $B$.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! also thanks to @YCor for all his nice counter-examples (one of his counter-examples appears in the answer).

Comment: In the first example you have to assume $k$ not of char 2 since otherwise $x^2+1$ is a square and indeed in this case there is an extension of the automorphism.

Comment: “Almost never”. Exactly the words I used in the blurb advertising my talk at Brown Wednesday last.

Comment: @YCor: ah, very good! I guess I was tacitly assuming $\operatorname{char}(k) = 0$, because that was a running assumption in the original post.